# How would I get a 2d car to turn realistically?

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, game-development, path-finding

I am making a tower defence game where the enemies are trucks, cars and tanks they all need to behave like 4 wheelers in terms of movement.

This is my code so far which got me somewhere(photos at the end including the desired and actual results), but I am not sure how to proceed to get somewhere near the desired result. Maybe there is some mathematical way to change every variable with respect to speed to get the movement I desire, maybe I need to rewrite all of it, in any way, I would appreciate the help.

```
//This is where we update the waypoint, this is relevant because we can change the distance where we consider the waypoint reached

    private void UpdateWaypoint()
    {
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, Route.waypoints[_currentWaypointIndex].position) <
            _waypointReachedDistance)
        {
            if (_currentWaypointIndex == Route.waypoints.Count - 1)
            {
                _hasReachedPlayerBase = true;
                if (loopBackToStart)
                    _currentWaypointIndex = 0;
                else
                    Invoke("Die", 2f);
            }
            else
            {
                _currentWaypointIndex++;
            }
        }
    }

 private void HandleTurning()
    {
        // Determine which direction to rotate towards
        Vector2 targetDirection = Route.waypoints[_currentWaypointIndex].position - transform.position;

        // The step size is equal to speed times frame time.
        float singleStep = turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime; 

        // Rotate the forward vector towards the target direction by one step
        float targetRad = Mathf.Atan2(targetDirection.y, targetDirection.x);

        float targetAngle = targetRad * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        float currentAngle = transform.eulerAngles.z; 
        float angleDelta = Mathf.DeltaAngle(currentAngle, targetAngle);

        if (Mathf.Abs(angleDelta) > singleStep)
        {
            float rotationAmount = Mathf.Sign(angleDelta) * singleStep;
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, rotationAmount);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, angleDelta);
        }
    }
```

[This is the game view currently, pink stuff are the tire marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huq5w.png)

[This is the scene view, orange ones are the waypoints, red ray is showing the next waypoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnn3e.png)

[This is where I would like to end up at, green stars are the waypoints, red line is the "road", black rectangle is the "car", black line is the desired trajectory of the car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP6yc.png)

Comment: Maybe try making the `_waypointReachedDistance` value larger, so that it starts turning when it is further away from the target, and you could also also decrease the `singleStep` value, so that it turns slower and has a wider turning arc. This should make turning look more realistic

Answer (score -2):

About your script to be honnest, I don't know ^^

I think you should try to use Nav Mesh Agent component for your cars.
There is a lot of tutorial on internet to use it with a car.

Comment: The question asker is asking about how to make their car turn more realistically - they already have a navigation system set up (using their own waypoint system). The Nav Mesh Agent component wouldn't help in this scenario.